# The usage of " inside-out and outside-in "

Tags: meaning, word-usage

> **Do we have both the usages of inside-out and outside-in?**

**inside-out** means: with the inner surface turned outward.

So basically they are the opposite meaning? Perform inside-out and then perform outside-in on an item A, then I suppose geometrically that we can turn A back to A itself?

And can we call this process of inside-out and outside-in as the $2\pi$=360 degree self-flipping?

Thanks.

Comment: You did know you should invert subject and predicate in questions?

Comment: _Outside in_ is not a common expression. It has been used sometimes paired with _inside out_, but I doubt that I have ever heard it on its own.

Answer (score 2):

*Inside out* and *outside in* are not opposites. They mean the same thing, at the same time.

Imagine a garment of fleece, such as a sweatshirt. The inside is fleecy, the outside is smooth. Turn it inside out. The fleecy side is outside now. Where is the smooth side? The smooth side is in; *the shirt is outside in*.

To say that something is inside out and outside in is a *redundancy*, the purpose of which is to reinforce or intensify. It's as if you were saying something was *thoroughly inside out.*

If you want a sequential use, it's more common to say *inside out and back again*.

You can posit that once a shirt is inside out, the inside becomes the new outside and vs. versa, but an inside out garment will really always be inside out.

Comment: Hope you're keeping well. When you decide that ELU is relaxation rather than a chore (if), could you kindly add a reference (eg Collins) justifying the statement/s in the first two sentences? Hope you keep well:)

Answer (score 0):

You understand the meaning of inside out (without the hyphen).  Say we have a pair of pants.  They can either be **inside out** to fix the pickets or **right-side out** to wear them.